# Why Expo local eas build on Linux fails?

Tags: javascript, android, linux, react-native, expo

I have set up windows subsystem for linux, installed node and eas to build my projects locally since I can not do it on Windows. When I try to run the build command I get the following error:

```
User@DESKTOP-AN12A:/mnt/d/Projects/myApp$ eas build --platform android --profile dev --local
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/command.js:52
            delete this.globalFlags?;
                                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/index.js:6:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

Not sure what to do :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like the eas-cli codebase is using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), which is not supported in Node version 13 or below. Make sure your Node version is 14 or above.